# SQL Query - Indirect joining of two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables like the following

Table1

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
 A       10     ABC
 A       11     ABC
 A       1      DEF
 A       2      DEF
 B       10     ABC
 B       11     ABC
 B       1      DEF
 C       3      DEF
 C       12     ABC
 C       21     GHI
```

Table2

```
COL1   GHI  ABC DEF
 A1    21   10  1
 A2    21   12  1
 A3    21   10  1
 A4    23   10  1
 A5    25   11  3
 A6    21   14  3
 A7    25   11  1
 A8    23   10  1
 A9    29   10  2
 A10   21   12  3
```

I have created another temporary table that returns all the distinct values from tbl1.col1

The values of col3 in tbl1 are columns in tbl2, which are populated by some values.

What I need is for each of these distinct values of table1.column1, `(A, B, C)` in this case, return a combination of **table2.column1** and **table1.column1** such that

- the ABC value of table2.column1 matches any of the ABC value of the "group" from table1,
- AND the DEF value of table2.column1 matches any of the DEF value of the "group" from table1,
- AND **IF THE GROUP CONTAINS GHI VALUES**, the GHI value of table2.column1 matches any of the GHI value of the "group" from table1

So, I would need something like the following

Output Table

```
Table2.COL1   Table1.Col1
     A1            A
     A3            A
     A4            A
     A7            A
     A8            A
     A9            A
     A1            B
     A3            B
     A4            B
     A7            B
     A8            B          
     A10           C
```

I tried something like this, but Im not sure if this is the right way of approaching

```
select table2.col1, temp_distinct_table.column1 
      from table2, temp_distinct_table
      where table2.def IN (SELECT col2 
                           FROM table1 
                           WHERE table1.col1 = temp_distinct_table.col1 
                                 AND table1.col3 = 'DEF')
      AND table2.abc IN (SELECT col2 
                         FROM table1 
                         WHERE table1.col1 = temp_distinct_table.col1 
                                 AND table1.col3 = 'ABC')
      AND (
          table2.ghi IN (SELECT col2 
                          FROM table1 
                          WHERE table1.col1 = temp_distinct_table.col1  
                                 AND table1.col3 = 'GHI') 
         OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 
                     FROM table1 
                     WHERE table1.col1 = temp_distinct_table.col1 
                       AND table1.col3 = 'GHI')
          )
```

where temp_distinct_table contains of all the distinct values from table1.col1

Could someone guide me on the matter?

Answer (score 3):

This becomes quite simple when you use collections (and you only need to do one table scan for each table):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE intlist AS TABLE OF INT;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t2.col1 AS t2_col1,
       t1.col1 AS t1_col1
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         CAST( COLLECT( CASE col3 WHEN 'ABC' THEN col2 END ) AS INTLIST ) AS abc,
         CAST( COLLECT( CASE col3 WHEN 'DEF' THEN col2 END ) AS INTLIST ) AS def,
         CAST( COLLECT( CASE col3 WHEN 'GHI' THEN col2 END ) AS INTLIST ) AS ghi
  FROM   table1
  GROUP BY col1
) t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON (    t2.abc MEMBER OF t1.abc
    AND t2.def MEMBER OF t1.def
    AND ( t2.ghi MEMBER OF t1.ghi OR t1.ghi IS EMPTY ) );
```

**Output**:

```
t2_col1 t1_col1
------- -------
A1      A
A3      A
A4      A
A7      A
A8      A
A9      A
A1      B
A3      B
A4      B
A7      B
A8      B
A10     C
```

**Update**

An alternative query without using collections (it is going to be more efficient than your query but probably less efficient than collections):

```
SELECT t2.col1,
       t1.col1
FROM   table1 t1
       CROSS JOIN
       table2 t2
GROUP BY t1.col1, t2.col1
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN t1.col2 = t2.abc AND t1.col3 = 'ABC' THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND    COUNT( CASE WHEN t1.col2 = t2.def AND t1.col3 = 'DEF' THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND    (  COUNT( CASE WHEN t1.col2 = t2.ghi AND t1.col3 = 'GHI' THEN 1 END ) > 0
       OR COUNT( CASE t1.col3 WHEN 'GHI' THEN 1 END ) = 0 )
ORDER BY t1.col1, t2.col1;
```

**Update 2**:

Changed from `CROSS JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.col1 AS t2_col1,
       t1.col1 AS t1_col1
FROM   (
         SELECT t1.*,
                COUNT( CASE col3 WHEN 'GHI' THEN 1 END )
                  OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ) AS has_ghi
         FROM   table1 t1
       ) t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON ( t1.col3 = 'ABC' AND t2.abc = t1.col2 )
       OR ( t1.col3 = 'DEF' AND t2.def = t1.col2 )
       OR ( t1.col3 = 'GHI' AND t2.ghi = t1.col2 )
GROUP BY t1.col1, t2.col1, t1.has_ghi
HAVING COUNT( CASE t1.col3 WHEN 'ABC' THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND    COUNT( CASE t1.col3 WHEN 'DEF' THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND    ( COUNT( CASE t1.col3 WHEN 'GHI' THEN 1 END ) > 0 OR has_ghi = 0 )
ORDER BY t1.col1, t2.col1;
```

Comment: This sounds great. But lets say, I dont have create permissions. Only read, then how can I go about doing this?

Comment: @aakashgupta.0205 Updated with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, counting how many matches there are for each `t1.col`/`t2.col` combination after joining all the possible matches:

```
select distinct t2_col1, t1_col1
from (
  select t2.col1 as t2_col1, t1.col1 as t1_col1, t1.ghi_count as t1_ghi_count,
    count(case when t1.col3 = 'ABC' then 1 end)
      over (partition by t1.col1, t2.col1) as abc_matches,
    count(case when t1.col3 = 'DEF' then 1 end)
      over (partition by t1.col1, t2.col1) as def_matches,
    count(case when t1.col3 = 'GHI' then 1 end)
      over (partition by t1.col1, t2.col1) as ghi_matches
  from (
    select t1.*,
      count(case when t1.col3 = 'GHI' then 1 end)
        over (partition by t1.col1) as ghi_count
    from table1 t1
  ) t1
  join table2 t2
  on (t1.col3 = 'ABC' and t2.abc = t1.col2)
  or (t1.col3 = 'DEF' and t2.def = t1.col2)
  or (t1.col3 = 'GHI' and t2.ghi = t1.col2)
)
where abc_matches > 0
and def_matches > 0
and (t1_ghi_count = 0 or ghi_matches > 0)
order by t1_col1, t2_col1;
```

Which with your sample data gets:

```
T2_COL T1_COL
------ ------
A1     A     
A3     A     
A4     A     
A7     A     
A8     A     
A9     A     
A1     B     
A3     B     
A4     B     
A7     B     
A8     B     
A10    C
```

Not sure if the efficiency of that will be significantly different to MTO's cross join with your real data.